# Is he confusing joists with stud?

Tags: terminology

This guy [is point to the wall](https://youtu.be/xnarltDAUZQ?t=37) and refers that as "joists"

[image]

Is he confusing joists with stud?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite possibly.

According to [this](https://www.zircon.com/2011/02/04/what-are-wall-studs-and-joists/) site,

> *"Wall studs are support beams in your home’s **walls**, they’re typically 16 to 24 inches apart."
>
> (...)
>
> "Joists are the support beams in your **floor and ceiling**. You need to find these if you want to hang light fixtures, ceiling fans or fix squeaky floors."*

Also, if you do a quick Google image search for **joist** and **stud**, the difference can also be seen.

Comment: Would you please name a few differences between joist and stud, besides where they are put on (walls, floor or ceiling)?